# When my search gives no results, don't tell me to search by tag!

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I was searching for [the programming language in which I initially learned programming](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=superlogo). The search engine told me:

```
Your search returned no matches.

Suggestions:

    Search within a specific set of tags:

    [tag] superlogo
    [tag] [another-tag] superlogo
```

This suggestion makes no sense. How is searching within a specific set of tags going to improve my search results if I have none?

The search engine should give different suggestions if there are no results, compared to if there are many, possibly irrelevant results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have removed the unhelpful suggestions with the last build, given that search is AND now, they didn't make any sense.